# Как зарезервировать массив PHP

Tags: php

Здраствуйте! каким образом можно зарезервировать место в массив?
Хочу делать типа

```
n = len(tree)

allow = [0]*n
```

Только на php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.splfixedarray.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верно понял о чем вы
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php

```
$allow = array_fill(0, len($tree), 0);
```